# Serializing an HtmlDocument exception 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I'm working on a search engine project and I want to save my search history in a file but I had a difficulty to save the `Html Document` I always find an exception:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.Serialization Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.4.6.0, Culture=neutral, Public Key Token=bd319b19eaf3b43a' is not marked as serializable.

What does this error mean?

Comment: What serializer are you using?  Can you share the code you are using to serialize your HtmlDocument?

Comment: It means that this type is not marked with [`[Serializable]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) so cannot be serialized by serializing its public and private fields.  See [Can i serialize HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623328/can-i-serialize-htmlagilitypack-htmldocument).  Does that answer your question, or do you actually need a workaround?  If the latter, please share the code you are currently using to serialize your `HtmlDocument`.